# Iphone Sdk check internet connection auotmatically in middle of the app?

Tags: iphone, sdk, connection

Iam currently checking the internet connection when i start the app first time but if i close the app and turn on the airplane mode and then run the app back its working or it should check the internet connection if i lose my wifi and it should say your internet connection lost or somthing like that. Any one have proper answer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Reachability API. Here's some code from the app delegate file of one of my projects.

```
// ivars
Reachability* hostReach;
Reachability* internetReach;
Reachability* wifiReach;

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note {

    Reachability *curReach = (Reachability *)[note object];

    if ([curReach currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] init] autorelease];
        alert.title = @"No network connection?";
        alert.message = @"No network connection.";
        alert.delegate = self;
        [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
        [alert show];

    } 

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];

    hostReach = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.test.com"] retain];
    [hostReach startNotifier];

    internetReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
    [internetReach startNotifier];

    wifiReach = [[Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi] retain];
    [wifiReach startNotifier];

    // controller setup
    viewController = [[CFSplashViewController alloc] init];

    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

// and of course, remember to release all those resources..
```